# .htaccess redirect all files in this directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've moved an email cache directory in a wordpress plugin and I want to leave an .htaccess file in the **old** directory to redirect to the new one

I've seriously googled and cannot find an answer that works to redirect files in current directory to a new one. For simplicity the htaccess must be in old directory

siteurl/wp-content/plugins/church-admin-cache/ to
siteurl/wp-content/uploads/church-admin-cache/

Answer (score 0):

RedirectPermanent should do the job.

```
RedirectPermanent /wp-content/plugins/church-admin-cache/ /wp-content/uploads/church-admin-cache/
```

Comment: It doesn't on my test site! It redirects to http://www.themoyles.co.uk/clients-test-area/wp-content/uploads/church-admin-cache/clients-test-area/wp-content/plugins/church-admin-cache/readme.txt

Comment: If you have /clients-test-area/ before you have to add it to both uris

Comment: It's going to go in a wordpress plugin where users will have all sorts of site urls and installations in sub directories. Is there an easier we to say hey this .htaccess applies to this directory and files are now in ../../uploads/church-admin-cache/ ?